# Error while updating property 'nativeActions' of view managed by ToolbarAndroid

Tags: react-native

Hi I am getting the above error when setting action on ToolbarAndroid in ReactNative. Can please someone help me pinpoint the reason. 
Many Thanks
My code

```
<ToolbarAndroid
                  style={styles.toolbar}
                  title="TestApp"
                  titleColor={Colors["ActionBarText"]}
                  navIcon={require('image!ic_launcher')}
                  contentInsetStart={50}
                  actions={[{title: 'Sync', icon:require('./res/image/action_sync_icon.png'), show: 'always'}]}
                  onActionSelected={this.onActionSelected}
                />
```

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKiFe.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was happening because the AppTheme should extend AppCompatTheme for the menu items to appear

Added below to Android Manifest

```
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

And defined the style

```
<resources>
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

This fixed the issue

Answer (score 1):

I received a similar error when using the `ToolbarAndroid` component. When I removed `show: 'always'` from the `actions` array everything worked.

It seems there is an issue when you tell it to always show the action menu item and there isn't room on the NavBar to show it.

So it should be:

```
<ToolbarAndroid
    style={styles.toolbar}
    title="TestApp"
    titleColor={Colors["ActionBarText"]}
    navIcon={require('image!ic_launcher')}
    contentInsetStart={50}
    actions={[
        { title: 'Sync', icon:require('.res/image/action_sync_icon.png') }
    ]}
    onActionSelected={this.onActionSelected}
/>
```

Comment: Hi Jeffrey Hyer, I figured out it was something to do with show field but when i remove it, the icon doesn't show at all. I tried changing the size of icon from 50x50 to 28x28 but no luck. Do you now what should be the size of the icon?

Comment: I don't know the proper size, I've been using an icon font and it handles the sizing dynamically :/ sorry

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen with react-native-vector-icons if you are passing an `iconName` attribute within `actions` that is not found within the font source.

Or if you are passing an `icon` attribute within `actions`, that doesn't make sense.